# Is it necessary to define a pole as being isolated?

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume poles were not defined as being isolated. The constant function $\infty$ would then be a function with non-isolated poles. My question is whether this would be the only case? This would then be in analogy with the fact that the only holomorphic function with non-isolated zeros must be the zero function.

So assume $f$ is meromorphic function, in the sense just defined (poles not being necessarily isolated). Consider an accumulation point of poles of $f$, say $a$ (note that $a$ can be infinity). I would somehow like to argue that
$$
\frac 1{f(z)}
$$
is then holomorphic around $a$. If this were the case, then we could use the fact that for holomorphic (non-zero) functions, the zeros are isolated. While I do see that
$$
\lim_{z\to a}\frac 1{f(z)}=0,
$$
I would still need that $1/f(z)$ is holomorphic on a punctured neighbourhood of $a$, for $1/f(z)$ to be holomorphic. Can I argue this? If not, I would be interested to see an example where this goes wrong.

Comment: just to clarify, what is your (usual) definition of a pole? a point $p$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on a punctured neighborhood of $p$ and $\lim_{z \to p} |f(z)|=+\infty$?

Comment: if so, what exactly do you mean by not requiring poles to be isolated?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I would say any point $p$ such that $\lim_{z\to p}\vert f(z)\vert=+\infty$, not saying anything about the analyticity of $f$, just as in the case of the definition of the zero of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not completely sure about what you mean, but I think this should be enough for a counterexample.

Take $f(z)=\text{Log } z$, the principal branch of logarithm, defined on $\mathbb C \backslash (-\infty, 0]$. Then $\lim_{z \to 0} |\text{Log } z |=+\infty$. However $\frac{1}{f}$ cannot be extended holomorphically near $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm convinced now that we really do need to ask for poles to be isolated.